# Python magic functions vs %%writefile

Tags: python

In this [document](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) it says that magic functions are "always surrounded by double underscores" (e.g. `__init__ or __lt__`). Then why is %%writefile called a magic function?

Comment: That's specific to IPython & not part of the language spec.

Comment: And the dunders are called magic *methods*.

Answer (score 2):

%%writefile is an IPython [cell magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics), not a magic method. Cell magics are different by line magics because they are identified by a double %.

IPyhton cell and line magics are specific to IPython. See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#magics) for further information.

Some constructs you can use in IPython do not exist in Python, and you get an error if you try to run them as Python commands, as stated in IPython guide:

> Unless expressed otherwise all of the construct you will see here will raise a SyntaxError if run in a pure Python shell, or if executing in a Python script.

This because IPython is a set of tools aimed at improving the experience of using Python interactively, easing some repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this [magic command in iPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-writefile) (note: *command*, not *function*), then that's your answer; it is a specific iPython extension, not part of the Python language itself.